# How to use lazy_static with async/await initializer?

Tags: rust, async-await

I am using [mongodb](https://crates.io/crates/mongodb) with [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) as my async runtime.

I want to initialize the MongoDB [`Client`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/2.3.0/mongodb/struct.Client.html) globally so I used the [lazy-static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate. The problem is that the client connects asynchronously, and `lazy_static!` doesn't support the `async` keyword:

```
use mongodb::Client;

async {
    let client = Client::with_uri_str(&env_var("MONGO_URL")).await.unwrap();
}
```

So how can I initialize the `client`?

Related:

- [alternative to using 'await' with lazy_static! macro in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351945/alternative-to-using-await-with-lazy-static-macro-in-rust)
- [Async/await support?](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs/issues/167) on the lazy-static issue tracker

Comment: If blocking on initialization is ok using whatever `block_on` function tokio provides instead of `await`ing the result will get the job done.

Comment: Your linked StackOverflow Q&A has the two suggestions I would have: either `block_on` or use a `OnceCell`. Why are the answers there insufficient?

Comment: As I understand it, what you're looking for is sort of a `OnceCell` wrapper that works like `lazy_static!`, except it is initialized with an `async` block instead of a closure. However, in this case, it seems like the `mongodb` library is poorly coded and the `with_uri_str` method doesn't really need to be `async`, so I would just use `block_on`.

Comment: Thanks to all for your time, but using your approach create new issues, I am still looking for answer, with minimum [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Coder-256,  @Aiden4 , @kmdreko, I tried  `OnceCell `, `futures::executor::block_on` , `tokio::runtime::Runtime::new` etc, they all create new problems, like [“Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536566/how-can-i-create-a-tokio-runtime-inside-another-tokio-runtime-without-getting-th) or "thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'cannot execute `LocalPool` executor from within another executor: EnterError'" and much more...

Comment: Honestly I’d open an issue with the `mongodb` repo since the root issue is that this method is needlessly `async`. Any other solution would really be more of a workaround. However I can’t imagine why `OnceCell` wouldn’t work, what was the error?

Comment: @Coder-256 you're right, but its not exactly `mongodb`'s fault. Setting up the client creates a "resolver" which if configured to use `async-std` will end up calling [`resolver()`](https://docs.rs/async-std-resolver/0.20.3/async_std_resolver/fn.resolver.html) or [`resolver_from_system_conf()`](https://docs.rs/async-std-resolver/0.20.3/async_std_resolver/fn.resolver_from_system_conf.html), which appear to be needlessly `async`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you use a new runtime and the lazy static is first used within the context of an existing runtime, like in this example:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use mongodb::Client;

lazy_static! {
    static ref CLIENT: Client = {
        tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async {
            let uri = std::env::var("MONGO_URL").unwrap();
            let client = Client::with_uri_str(&uri).await.unwrap();

            client
        })
    };
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _db = CLIENT.database("local");
}
```

You'll get the error mentioned:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.', C:\Users\kmdreko\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-1.6.1\src\runtime\enter.rs:39:9
```

You *may* be able to circumvent this by using a different runtime (`futures` vs `tokio` vs `async-std`) but that's not ideal since it'd still be blocking the underlying one.

---

A relatively straight-forward way to solve this is *not* try to do it lazily and initialize it immediately in `main`. That way you can utilize an asynchronous runtime directly and not worry about needing one elsewhere:

```
use mongodb::Client;
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;

static CLIENT: OnceCell<Client> = OnceCell::new();

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let uri = std::env::var("MONGO_URL").unwrap();
    let client = Client::with_uri_str(&uri).await.unwrap();
    CLIENT.set(client).unwrap();

    let _db = CLIENT.get().unwrap().database("local");
}
```

This can be done via `OnceCell` (as seen above) or something like a `RwLock` if necessary. **Update**: [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) is also now in the standard library that does the same thing.

---

The most direct answer to what you're trying to achieve would be to use the [async_once](https://crates.io/crates/async_once) crate, which makes it use the receiver's runtime to drive the asynchronous function.

```
use async_once::AsyncOnce;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use mongodb::Client;

lazy_static! {
    static ref CLIENT: AsyncOnce<Client> = AsyncOnce::new(async {
        let uri = std::env::var("MONGO_URL").unwrap();
        let client = Client::with_uri_str(&uri).await.unwrap();

        client
    });
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _db = CLIENT.get().await.database("local");
}
```

This assumes all or nearly all uses of the client will be in asynchronous contexts.

Or you can use [`OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.33.0/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) from tokio, which is like `OnceCell`/`OnceLock` except its initializer is `async` like `AsyncOnce` so you can initialize it in `main` or separately through a helper function:

```
use mongodb::Client;
use tokio::sync::OnceCell;

static CLIENT: OnceCell<Client> = OnceCell::const_new();

async fn get_client() -> &'static Client {
    CLIENT.get_or_init(|| async {
        let uri = std::env::var("MONGO_URL").unwrap();
        let client = Client::with_uri_str(&uri).await.unwrap();

        client
    })
    .await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _db = get_client().await.database("local");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without `await` or `unwrap`, like ` let _db = CLIENT.get()`, same as when using `once_cell::sync::Lazy`?

Comment: @ZiiMakc Those are your main options: you either pre-initialize it (and thus `.get()` may fail if not actually initialized) or lazy-initialize it (and thus you need `.await` to drive the asynchronous initialization). The only way to avoid both is to *block* while initializing, which the only sane way to do that (in tokio) would be [`block_in_place`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html).