# Rust's Lazy init (OnceCell crate) does not work everywhere

Tags: asynchronous, rust, discord, lazy-loading

I'm writing a discord bot in Rust with [Serenity](https://docs.rs/serenity/latest/serenity/index.html).
In order to populate some embed headers, I need bot-related info (user & owner, hereafter named `BOT`) and I'm trying to use the [`Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html#) struct from the [once_cell](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/index.html) crate to make that happen.

The catch is that this `BOT` data can only be queried using async functions with serenity's Http module and I'm struggling to make that work.

I set up a few slash-commands that each have their own handler function. When I dereference `BOT` (this is what's supposed to evaluate it (only once), right ?) from one of those handler functions, my `Lazy` closure blocks on the first `.await` it encounters.

On the other hand, it just works when I dereference `BOT` from `main` (tokio async).

The following code therefore prints "0,1,2,3" when dereferencing `BOT` from `main` but only "0,1" when doing so from a specific slash-command handler (BoxedFuture) :

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use serenity::{http::Http, model::user::User};

pub struct Bot {
    pub user: User,
    pub owner: User,
}

pub static BOT: Lazy<Bot> = Lazy::new(|| {
    println!("0");
    let http_client = Http::new(env!("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"));

    futures::executor::block_on(async {
        println!("1");
        let user = http_client
            .get_current_user()
            .await
            .expect("An HTTP client error occured")
            .into();

        println!("2");
        let owner = http_client
            .get_current_application_info()
            .await
            .expect("An HTTP client error occured")
            .owner;

        println!("3");
        Bot { user, owner }
    })
});
```

Can anyone explain why that is ?

Comment: You can't use `block_on` inside of an async task. It would block the async loop, causing a deadlock. You can **never** call anything blocking inside of an async task. This is true even though your `Lazy` closure is not an async closure, if you are accessing `BOT` from withing async tasks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust lazy\_static with async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650879/rust-lazy-static-with-async-await)

Comment: I don't think that the link you provided answers my question. I've stumbled upon it already but didn't manage to get sth working. I'll give it another look though.
What I need now given you comment is a way to replace that `block_on` call.

Comment: No, what you are trying to do is just simply not possible without a non-async once. The answer in the duplicate lays it out exactly as you need it. You will never be able to execute async code from within a sync function that is called from another async. The calling order async -> sync -> async is an impossible situation, because there is no way to propagate an `await` through a sync function without blocking the executor. Your sync needs to become async, like shown with `AsyncOnce` in the duplicate.

Comment: The last example is almost 1:1 your situation, where a server connection needs to be instantiated globally and lazily.

Comment: Do you think the [`async-once-cell`](https://crates.io/crates/async-once-cell) crate could do what I need ? I'm trying to instantiate a `Lazy` with the `new()` method but the compiler isn't happy about it and I can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Probably, I'm not familiar with that crate. There is usually many ways to solve a problem.

Comment: If you make sure to dereference it (or call `force()`) at the beginning of `main()`, it _should_ be fine, but I would not rely on that. If you do it before you construct the runtime it should be fine. But you need to consider whether you are ready to pay the price of always initializing it, even when unnecessary.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think your answer here would make a worthy addition to the linked Q&A if you'd like to duplicate it over there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should **never** block inside an async runtime. Never, ever.

You can use [`tokio::sync::OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) instead of `once_cell`:

```rust
pub async fn get_bot() -> &'static Bot {
    static BOT: tokio::sync::OnceCell<Bot> = tokio::sync::OnceCell::const_new();
    BOT.get_or_init(|| async {
        println!("0");
        let http_client = Http::new(env!("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"));

        println!("1");
        let user = http_client
            .get_current_user()
            .await
            .expect("An HTTP client error occured")
            .into();

        println!("2");
        let owner = http_client
            .get_current_application_info()
            .await
            .expect("An HTTP client error occured")
            .owner;

        println!("3");
        Bot { user, owner }
    })
    .await
}
```

Comment: I went with a variant of your snippet :
1. declare a static BOT variable. 2. use serenity's `ready` event to initialize it on startup. 3. implement a `get_data` function to avoid having to `.get().unwrap()` everytime I need to access the data